# Why is this code sending duplicate emails?

Tags: node.js, email, azure, sendgrid

We're running a scheduler on Azure that runs every minute and checks in a database to see what emails need to be sent for our app and sends them.

This works the vast majority of the time but once in a while, for a few hours, the scheduler starts sending most emails in duplicates (up to 5 copies).

```
    query = "select id, email, textbody, htmlbody, subject from emailTable where sent = 0 AND DateSent IS NULL";
mssql.query(query, {
    success: function(results) {
        for(var i = 0 ; i < results.length; i++)
        {
            handleItem(results[i]);
        }
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log("Error : " + err);
    }
});

function handleItem(item) {
        sendMail(item); 
        var query = "update emailTable SET sent = 1, DateSent = GETDATE() where id = ?";
        mssql.query(query, [item.id]);

}

function sendMail(objMail)
{
    sendgrid.send({
      to:       objMail.email,
      from:     'source@sourcemail.com',
      fromname: "Source",
      subject:  objMail.subject,
      text:     objMail.textbody,
      html:     objMail.htmlbody
    }, function(err, json) {
      if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    });
}
```

When it starts failing it's as if `handleItem` or `sendMail` is called multiple times for the same item. Is there anything wrong with the loop or the general logic that would explain this behavior ?

Comment: Is it possible that the task could take longer than a minute, and another scheduler would start running and see some unsent e-mails that are already queued by the first scheduler?  We use sendgrid and sometimes there are network hiccups which cause email timeout.  In that case, it may take a whole minute to (fail to) send a single email...

Comment: We considered this, but from our understanding Azure should limit it to one scheduler running at a time. Also, when looking at the logs, I'm seeing  every duplicate mail for an adress being sent at the same time which I don't think would be the case if it was a new scheduler starting. Still, I will try testing the behavior of schedulers to see if we're correct in our assumptions.

Comment: do you have any database replication or anything that might cause your data to go out of sync temporarily?

Comment: have you checked which function runs duplicate times in loop, `handleItem()` or `sendMail()`? Or will it query duplicate items?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try writing the update query in the callback function for sendMail(item)

eg. sendMail(item,function(){
 var query = "update emailTable SET sent = 1, DateSent = GETDATE() where id = ?";
        mssql.query(query, [item.id]);
});

function sendMail(objMail,cb)
{
    sendgrid.send({
      to:       objMail.email,
      from:     'source@sourcemail.com',
      fromname: "Source",
      subject:  objMail.subject,
      text:     objMail.textbody,
      html:     objMail.htmlbody
    }, function(err, json) {
      if (err) { cb(err) }
       cb(null,json)
    });
}
```

Comment: Why would this fix a problem of duplicates?

Comment: As per my understanding your sendMail is getting executed many times before updation of your database.

Comment: This actually updates the database even later than the OP's code.